# Sending data from clients to server

Tags: python, api, flask, raspberry-pi, python-requests

I have to complete a programming project at college and I have decided on a project that will require multiple clients (raspberry pis) to interact with a central server.

Essentially, the server will store a database of people each with a unique vector. Then, a raspberry pi will send a vector to the server and the server will then determine which vector it is closest to out of the ones it has stored in that database, and then it will update a status database accordingly.

A web application will display the live status of certain variables in the status database, and people should be able to login to the web application (but that doesn't need to be achieved now, giving anyone on the local network access to it for now is fine).

I'm just not quite sure how to set this up. I have already made the web application in flask and at the moment it is running locally but I think I can make it accessible on the whole network by changing the host to 0.0.0.0.

I have also written the code to take multiple vectors as input and then check them all and update the database accordingly. However, I am not yet sure how to send the vectors from the Pi to the server.

Since it is still in the development phase at the moment, my PC will be the server and I'll be using a single Rasperry Pi 3B as a client.

I was thinking I might need to send a POST request from the Pi to the server and I can do that since I have experience with python requests, although I wouldn't know how to configure it to send it to the server and then have the server read it and execute the code to analyse the vector(s).

So I was essentially just wondering if someone could help me tie all of this together, and if you have any suggestions for anything I should change or add then that would be very helpful. If anything is unclear then please let me know and I'll try and clarify.

Thanks.

EDIT: Seems like I probably need an API on my server and then I send a POST request to http://MY_PC_IP/{api} and then somehow get that data into Python so I can run my code with it?

Answer (score 1):

you could create a route in your flask app that takes the vector sent from a raspberry as input and then processes this data accordingly. The post data you are sending could perhaps be a JSON style formatting.

Also yes, run your app with 'host=0.0.0.0'. Now from another computer (raspberry for example) you can connect to the server by using the ip-adress of your server.

The following example should work.

```
from flask import request,jsonify

@app.route('/post_vector',methods=['POST'])
def post_vector():
    if not request.is_json:
        return jsonify({"Message":"Missing JSON in request"})
    vector = request.json.get("vector", None)
    #now do something with vector. like DB comparison or whatever.
    return jsonify({"Message": vector})
```

then from your raspberry you can create a script that posts its vector to your flask app.

```
import requests
import json

uri = <ip-address-of-server> + '/post_vector'
data = {
  "vector" : "somevector"
}
data = json.dumps(data)
response = requests.post(uri, data=data)
reply = json.loads(response.text)
print(reply)
```

Comment: Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: That looks fantastic, thank you very much. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Hi, I'm having a bit of trouble with the POST request. I did `ipconfig` on my main PC and I took my IPV4 address from there. And then did `requests.post(http://<ip>/post_vector, data={'message': 'test'})` but I got an error (ConnectionRefusedError: Connection refused). Any ideas?

Comment: Okay turns out I forgot to set the host to 0.0.0.0. Now I've done that I get a 405 Forbidden status.

Comment: Okay... I was doing `requests.get`... Now I fixed that I'm stilling having issues. See this: https://pastebin.com/7hGjb9QH

Comment: Fixed that by doing `return 'abc'`, but for some reason data_dict is still None.

Comment: Okay fixed a lot of stuff but ultimately now running into a 400 bad request error https://pastebin.com/3UfXK5V8

Comment: Sorry for all the messages lol... Everything seems to be working now https://pastebin.com/2zaYqbCm. Anything you'd change?

Comment: That looks great JP, glad you got it working.
i'd only change your `request.json.get("message", None)`.
This ensures that if a message without name 'message' is set you get None as return instead of catching and error and causing your program to crash. ps.dont forget to click the upvote button if this helped ;)

Comment: and related to your Error message : "view function did not return a response", Flask views prefer to have a response returned...hence the 'return' statements in my code.